# Display contents of an array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=asedAWWefefI-43WqNAiw0XkfflwpU9zqkg">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("jquery", "1.6.1");
            </script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
                {...
}....
```

My code fails to work I guess it is the above code's fault.

The whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyDzbTUhnU2I-erwerwe3450XkfflwpU9zqkg">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.6.1");
        </script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
            {
                $(function()
                {
                    $('#catalog').click(function(e)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.getJSON('books.php', function(data) {   
                            var book = "<h3>" + data.title + </h3>";                             
                            book += "<p>ISBN: " + data.isbn + "</p>";                                                
                            book += "<br/>Published Date: " + data.publishDate;
                            book += "<br/>Publisher: " + data.publisher;
                            var author = [];

                            $.each(data.authors, function(i, ov) {
                                authors.push(ov.name)
                            });

                            book += "<br/>Authors: " + authors.join(", ");
                            $('#resopnse').html(book);
                                                                                                                                            });
                    });
                });
            });                                              
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a id="catalog" href="">Retrieve book information</a></p>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i click the link it doesn't show me anything.I already have a books.php file with an array formatted to have a json output.

**UPDATE**

```
$.getJSON('books.php', function(data)
                        {
                            var book = "<h3>" + data.title + "</h3>";
                            book += "<p>ISBN: " + data.isbn + "</p>";
                            book += "<br/>Published Date: " + data.publishDate;
                            book += "<br/>Publisher: " + data.publisher;
                            var author = [];
                            $.each(data.authors, function(i, ov) { authors.push(ov.name) });
                            book += "<br/>Authors: " + authors.join(", ");
                            $('#response').html(book);

                        });
```

This function can't be reached inside.

Comment: `$('#resopnse').html()`... Is that a typo in the code?

Comment: Put an alert inside your $('#catalog').click(function(){ alert('test');}); and check if its working

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript error on your page. You should really use a debugger. Chrome dev tools is excellent. press [ctr][shift][j] if you are using chrome or menu > tools > js console

```
var book = "<h3>" + data.title + </h3>";
```

Missing "